# Adding a contact using only the Organization field sorts the item under "#"

Tags: ios

After I create and add the contact, it shows up in the people picker at the bottom in the "#" section as if the last name started with a number.

```
newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"", &error); // no first
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"", &error);  // no last
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, @"ACME Rockets", &error);
multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, phoneNumber, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone, nil);
CFRelease(multiPhone);

ABAddressBookAddRecord(appDelegate.addressBook, newPerson, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(appDelegate.addressBook, &error);
```

If I do the same through the iOS Address Book app, it sorts the contact correctly under the first letter in the organization field.

Have I found a bug, or is there a sort property I need to set when first and last are blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution:

Notice I was setting first and last to @"".

```
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"", &error); // no first
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"", &error);  // no last
```

By removing these statements, the contact gets correctly sorted by the Organization field.